# Javascript report in Netsuite not showing every line

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, netsuite

In netsuite's ssp pages for sitebuilder denali, I have javascript search that I built to pull information off of the invoice document and 2 lines off of the item document.  The search is working just fine, but is being flattened(ie it is returning only one line of results for each internal id, despite there being multiple values for some of the custom fields), there are no filters, mainline or otherwise, currently applied, though I have tried it with mainline set to false and it makes no difference. 
The relevant lines of code are:

```js
  var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', null, filters, columns);
        return _.map(searchResults, function(result) {
          return {
            internalid: result.getValue('internalid'),
            date: result.getValue('trandate'),
            DocNum: result.getValue('tranid'),
   TotalAmount: result.getValue('total'),
   status: result.getValue('entitystatus'),
   PONum: result.getValue('otherrefnum'),
   WellNum: result.getValue('custbody9'),
   WellName: result.getValue('custbody8'),
   fivecode: result.getValue('custitem35','item'),
   desc: result.getValue('itemid','item'),
   Reason: result.getValue('custbody67'),   
   Tech: result.getValue('custbody38')   
          };
        });
```

How do I get every line returned to show?

Comment: You're going to need to apply some sort of filter or search id otherwise that search will produce at least one line for every invoiced item in your account. (it will try but will only return 1000 lines). I don't believe underscore does anything to flatten but try replacing _.map with `searchResults.map(function(result){});`. I know the built in map doesn't do any flattening.

Comment: Replacing searchResults gives an error unfortunately.

Comment: about the only thing underscore does for you is guard against nulls. 
`return _.map(searchResults, function(result){});` and `return (searchResults || []).map(function(result){});` should be equivalent in a server side script or in Firefox, Chrome or some recent version of IE.

Comment: The error I am getting is TypeError: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaArray@54c1f688 is not a function, it is object. (ssp_libraries.js#5553) maybe I am missing something?

Comment: You'd have to paste in your code. Usually this is something like forgetting the array function. e.g. `searchResults(function(result){...});` instead of `searchResults.map(function(result){...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is likely that NetSuite is skipping the line items because of more than 1000 results.

you can either sort the results by `internalid` by adding a search column

```
columns.push[new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid').setSort()]
```

This will show you multiple results for your `internalid` but still some invoices may not come in the search results.

Or else, You could use below code to search and bring all results

```
var search = nlapiCreateSearch('invoice', filters, columns).runSearch();
var res = [],
    currentRes;

var i = 0;

while(i % 1000 === 0){
  currentRes = (search.getResults(i, i+1000) || []);
  res = res.concat(currentRes);
  i = i + currentRes.length;
}
```

Finally, you could use your code to flatten

```
return _.map(res, function(result) {
          return {
            internalid: result.getValue('internalid'),
            date: result.getValue('trandate'),
            DocNum: result.getValue('tranid'),
            TotalAmount: result.getValue('total'),
            status: result.getValue('entitystatus'),
            PONum: result.getValue('otherrefnum'),
            WellNum: result.getValue('custbody9'),
            WellName: result.getValue('custbody8'),
            fivecode: result.getValue('custitem35','item'),
            desc: result.getValue('itemid','item'),
            Reason: result.getValue('custbody67'),          
            Tech: result.getValue('custbody38')         
          };
        });
```